# how to deploy netbeans .war on jetty out of netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jetty, jax-rs

I created a webservice successfully tested on glassfish within netbeans , which uses POST and give back results as follows:

```
@Path("caas")
public class Cribservice {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    public Cribservice() {
        TimeZone theTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
     }
    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public void setJson(String p) {
        String x = p;
        System.out.println(x);
        run(x);
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/postid")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String halloween(String p){
        int sizy;
     return some string;
    }
}
```

I dont have any web.xml but using ApplicationConfig.java

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestResourceClasses();
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify this method. It is automatically generated by NetBeans REST support.
     */
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(cribservice.Cribservice.class);
        return resources;
    }

}
```

> I tried to deploy this app on jetty on localmachine out of netbeans ,
>   but i am not able to access my services , all i am able to see is
>   helloworld on local browser when i access  localhost:8080/caas

Answer (score 0):

So before deploying your project on jetty out of netbeans. First make sure you have all the related jetty-web.xml and other required files.

In order to generate these files , install jetty plugin for netbeans,
Download jetty server from internet
Create a new project , select jetty as a server and point it to location of jetty.
Then create your project , test it and deploy it after you paste your generated .war in /webapps folder